# Listview reference in a class library

Tags: asp.net-3.5, class-library, system.web.ui.webcontrols

I'm trying to access the ListView class from System.Web.UI.WebControls in my class library.

So I added a reference to System.Web and expected it to then show up but unfortunately it didn't. Now I can only assume it is because the ListView is part of the 3.5 release not 2.0. So I checked my class library to make sure it is targeting 3.5 and not 2.0 and it is definately referencing the 3.5 framework.

Does anyone have any ideas what I've missed to still not see ListView in the correct namespace?

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference choose System.Web.Extensions from the .net tab

Comment: I don't have the problem any more unfortunately so can't test your answer. I'll up vote you and if you get more from other people fixing the problem with your answer I will accept it.